# Why am I getting MissingMethodException even though I inject dependencies with ninject?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-5, ninject

When I try to access the Exams view, I get this error. I don't understand, because everything seems to be ok.

Error:

> [MissingMethodException: No constructor without parameters has been defined for this object.]
> System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance (RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean & canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal & ctor, Boolean & bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
> System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow (Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark & ​​stackMark) +122
> System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor (Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark & ​​stackMark) +239
> System.Activator.CreateInstance (Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +85
> System.Activator.CreateInstance (Type type) +12
> System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create (RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +55

> [InvalidOperationException: An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'ConsultaH.MVC.Controllers.ExamesController'. Make sure the controller has a parameterless public constructor.]
> System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create (RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +178
> System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance (RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +80
> System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController (RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName) +102
> System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit (HttpContextBase httpContext, IController & controller, IControllerFactory & factory) +188
> System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest (HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +50
> System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest (HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +48
> System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest (HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +16
> System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute () +105
> System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl (IExecutionStep step) +50
> System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep (IExecutionStep step, Boolean & completedSynchronously) +163

My code inside **NinjectWebCommon.cs**:

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
            kernel.Bind(typeof(IAppServiceBase<>)).To(typeof(AppServiceBase<>));
            kernel.Bind<IPacienteAppService>().To<PacienteAppService>();
            kernel.Bind<IExameAppService>().To<ExameAppService>();
            kernel.Bind<ITipoExameAppService>().To<TipoExameAppService>();
            kernel.Bind<IConsultaAppService>().To<ConsultaAppService>();

            kernel.Bind(typeof(IServiceBase<>)).To(typeof(ServiceBase<>));
            kernel.Bind<IPacienteService>().To<PacienteService>();
            kernel.Bind<IExameService>().To<ExameService>();
            kernel.Bind<ITipoExameService>().To<TipoExameService>();
            kernel.Bind<IConsultaService>().To<ConsultaService>();

            kernel.Bind(typeof(IRepositoryBase<>)).To(typeof(RepositoryBase<>));
            kernel.Bind<IPacienteRepository>().To<PacienteRepository>();
            kernel.Bind<IExameRepository>().To<ExameRepository>();
            kernel.Bind<ITipoExameRepository>().To<TipoExameRepository>();
            kernel.Bind<IConsultaRepository>().To<ConsultaRepository>();

}
```

My **ExamesController.cs** class:

```
public class ExamesController : Controller
{
        private readonly IExameAppService _exameApp;       

        public ExamesController(IExameAppService exameApp)
        {
            _exameApp = exameApp;            
        }

        // GET: Exame
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var exames = _exameApp.GetAll();
            var exameViewModel = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Exame>, IEnumerable<ExameViewModel>>(exames);            

            return View(exameViewModel);
        }
}
```

I put a breakpoint in the class **NinjectWebCommon.cs** in the method *CreateKernel()* and always is given an error when reaching the first line after the attempt, this error occur at run time. See code below:

```
private static IKernel CreateKernel()
{
            var kernel = new StandardKernel();
            try
            {
                kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel); // <= This line
                kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();
                RegisterServices(kernel);
                return kernel;
            }
            catch
            {
                kernel.Dispose();
                throw;
            }
}
```

I researched a lot and I can't find any solution in this case.

Comment: Maybe this can help https://stackoverflow.com/a/37926152/1236044

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do to resolve this error was to uninstall the Ninject default package and install a package called Ninject MVC5.